# Diferença de proporção do layout entre o Form1.cs[Design] e o .exe

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Recentemente eu estou programando uma aplicação WindowsForms usando c#, e tem meio que um bug acontecendo com o IDE que deixa a proporção do layout diferente, como na imagem abaixo:
[image: l]

O formulário do lado esquerdo é o que o IDE me apresenta antes de executar a solução, e o do lado direito é o gerado depois do build. Se olharem atentamente vão perceber algumas diferenças de proporção dos elementos entre eles, até o próprio tamanho do formulário gerado é diferente.

Gostaria de saber o que eu posso fazer para deixar ambos na mesma proporção, isso acaba me iludindo no momento de arrumar o layout do formulário.

Comment: Percebi que esse bug visual acontece quando eu aumento o tamanho da fonte, tanto do label quanto do button.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando o windows forms então aconselho a utilizar a propriedade anchor para fixar suas proporções e distancias relativas a borda do formulário, se você colocar o anchor como top em todos os seus campos inputs eles manterão a distâncias verticais entre eles, mesmo que a janela seja redimensionada.

Caso queira estudar um pouco mais de design com o windows form existe um canal do youtube chamado [C# Ui Academy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCigNaporFrKIPHiF1FcWfwA) que ensina diversos truques de design no windows form, o que lhe daria um melhor conhecimento das propriedades colocando em prática.

Comment: Coloquei como top, mas mesmo assim continua dando aquela diferença de proporção, isso só acontece quando eu aumento o tamanho da fonte, não to entendendo isso.

Comment: Quando você aumenta o tamanho da fonte os inputs se adaptam ao tamanho da mesma, como os inputs aumentam de tamanho eles ocupam o espaço  da margem entre eles, caso você aumente mais eles acabariam se sobrepondo. Sendo assim se você não alterar o tamanho da fonte ele ficará no local que você determinou. Você necessita que os inputs mudem o tamanho da fonte?

Comment: Neste caso eu preciso sim

Comment: Mas o problema está no tamanho da fonte do label, quando eu aumento o tamanho dela mesmo mantendo uma distância viável entre o label e o text box, o label ainda fica sobrepondo o text box.

Comment: Neste caso você pode manter a distância via código, por exemplo você colocaria no seu código dentro de algum evento da janela :`textbox.Left = label.Left + label.Width + 10` assim ele manteria uma distancia de 10 pixels mesmo que o tamanho e posição da label seja alterada.

Answer (score 0):

Observe no método `InitializeComponents()` se a configuração abaixo foi inserida:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

Altere para:

```
this.AutoScaleMode =  System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
```

Eu não consegui simular o mesmo erro no meu ambiente, observe se essa configuração irá resolver seu problema.

Eu encontrei essa solução a partir dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554883/windows-forms-sizes-not-matching) (em inglês)

Esperto ter ajudado. Abraço.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/233882)

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pelo feedback. Fiz a edição nesta resposta para tentar melhorá-la. Vou me atentar mais para a questão. Abraço.